# Joining groups separated by an empty line

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a file with contents:

```
aaa bbb ccc
jjj kkkk llll qqqq
www ee rrrr

kkkk oooo ppp wwww
kk aaa dd

aa eee tttt
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
aaa bbb ccc jjj kkk llll qqqq www ee rrrr
kkkk oooo ppp wwww kk aaa dd
aa eee tttt
```

Notice that the empty lines separate the blocks of lines, and that the new lines within each block are replaced by space.

My solution is very ugly, I start by replacing empty lines by a separator e.g. "|", then replace all newlines by space and finally replace the separator "|" by a newline. Has anybody a more elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done easily with `awk`:

```
awk -v RS= '{gsub(/\n/, " "); print}' file
aaa bbb ccc jjj kkkk llll qqqq www ee rrrr
kkkk oooo ppp wwww kk aaa dd
aa eee tttt
```

Here `-v RS=` sets record separator to empty string that makes awk read multiple lines (until an empty line appears) as a single record.

**Update:** Even simpler awk can be: (**thanks to @jaypal**)

```
awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1' file
```

Comment: Yes it does, I myself tested it on OSX.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/\n./s/\n/ /;ta;P;d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this sed command ,

```
sed ':a ;N;/\n$/{P;d;t} ; s/\n/ /g ; t a' File_name
```

**Explanation :**

```
N           - Getting two lines 
s/\n/ /g    - replace newline to space 
: a and ta  - Execute the loop and append each and every line .
              (So every line become a single line ).
/\n$/       - matching end with new line then break the loop and and start from the first .
{P,d,t}     - print the pattern space First line and delete the pattern space and start 
              the loop
```

Comment: This works. Can you explain the workings of this sed? By the way, on Mac one should use GNU version of sed.

Comment: @xeon Simpler version with GNU `sed` would be `sed ':a;N;/\n$/!ba;s/\n/ /g' file`

Comment: @xeon: Yes OSX default `sed` didn't work, had to use `gsed`. But even that has few issues: 1. Shows first record as `qqqqwww ee rrrr` instead of `qqqq www ee rrrr` 2. It shows empty lines if there are multiple empty lines between records. I guess it needs to change to `s/\n/ /g` in sed command but empty lines remain in case there are multiple of them.

Answer (score 0):

Through perl,

```
perl -i -00pe 's/(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/ /g; s/\n\n/\n/g' file
```